# Wildcard with extends

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Code:

```
List<? extends Integer> ints= new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(new SomeType());
```

I'm trying to reason why we cant add to `ints` formally. Please check the correctness.

Compiler always matched question mark to anonymous type `CAP#n`, where `n` is the ordinal number of wildcard declaration in the source code. From the fact that this wildrcard with extends implies that compiler internally assigned `CAP#1` (in that case) just to anonymous type of `null`. But i'm not sure in this reason. Consider

```
List<? super Integer> ints= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
ints.add(new Object());//error
```

In this case we have that compiler internally creates a new anonymous type, who marked `CAP#2`, such that only instance of all `Integer's` supertype is "instance of" `CAP#2`.

**Question** Do I understand the principle of wildcard's working correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to look at the presented problem in different view, from java.util.List

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
    *
    *

    boolean add(E e);

    *
    *
}
```

When you specify `List<? extends Integer>`, the argument for **add()** becomes **'? extends Integer'**. From that description, the compiler cannot know which specific sub type of **Integer** is required there, so it won't accept any type of **Integer**.

The usage of `List<? super Integer>` tells to compiler that the it's possible to add to the list everything that is super type of **Integer**, addition of other types will violate static type safety.

You can thus begin to think of subtypes and supertypes bounds in terms of how you can "write" (pass into a method) to a generic type, and "read" (return from a method) from generic type.

Basically your technical description is right but I think that my explanation is more reasonable from  static type safety point of view.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I understand that _compiler cannot know which specific sub type of Integer is required there, so it won't accept any type of Integer._ and _The usage of List<? super Integer> tells to compiler that the it's possible to add to the list everything that is super type of Integer, addition of other types will violate static type safety._. But i want to realize how it works formally. I.e. why the error's description is `excepted add(Object,int) found add(CAP#1,int)`. I want to know is it trues that compiler works as i said in my question? If yes, please told me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore the fact that Integer is final for purposes of this discussion.

When you give a variable the type of `List< ? extends Integer >`, the compiler does not allow you to call any method of List which has the generic type parameter as an argument to a method. These parameters are in what is known as contravariant position, and if the compiler would allow you to do what you are trying to do, Java's type system would be even more unsound than it already is.  All the compiler knows is that the element type of the List is some unknown subtype of Integer, internally called CAP#1.  Now attempting to call `add( CAP#1, int )` with anything at all as first parameter will fail. The only exception is `null`, simply because unlike any other value in Java, null is a member of every reference type, so it must be a member of CAP#1.  Note that the compiler *will* allow you to call any method of a `List< ? extends Integer >` that has no generic type inputs but possibly *produces* generic type outputs.

Contrary to the answer given by @Maxim Kirilov, when you give a variable the type of `List< ? super Integer >`, the compiler does *not* allow you to add any supertype of Integer. All it knows is that the unknown type is some supertype of Integer, internally called CAP#2, and that therefore anything which is an Integer or any *subtype* S of Integer can be added to the list (because no matter what CAP#2 turns out to be, S is a subtype of Integer which is a subtype of CAP#2, so `add( CAP#2, int )` will accept an S in the first parameter).

By contrast, you are trying to call the method with an Object, which is *not* a subtype of Integer. The compiler rejects an attempt to pass an Object where a CAP#2 is required (as explained above).

Comment: _All the compiler knows is that the element type of the List is some unknown subtype of Integer, internally called CAP#1. Now attempting to call add( CAP#1, int ) with anything at all as first parameter will fail. The only exception is null, simply because unlike any other value in Java, null is a member of every reference type, so it must be a member of CAP#1._ From this doesn implies that we cant add   to `ints` nothing from `null`. If we say that `CAP#1` equivalent to anonymous type of `null` then it's OK. Or i dont understand you correct?

Comment: `null` has _every_ non-primitive type, not just `CAP#1` or `Integer` or `Map<String, ? super Doohickey< Enum< ? > > >`; do you not see this yet?  In Scala the type system assigns the formal name AnyRef to this type.  The reason you cannot add anything except null to a List of CAP#1 is because whatever argument you pass in, even an `Integer`, the compiler can't figure out the relationship between that type and `CAP#1`.  You did not, and can not, declare any such relationship because the type is a wildcard. However, it is a mistake to say that `CAP#1` is _equivalent_ to `AnyRef`.